# DrawerLayout with Achartengine GraphicalView Linechart

Tags: android, android-layout, achartengine, linechart

Why **Linechart sinks** on sliding drawer slide ? Anyone have face this problem please help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try to use the following method in order to get rid of this behavior:

```
mRenderer.setInScroll(true);
```